# Adding MarkerStroke color adds thick lines when Smooth is true

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, oxyplot

I have following `AreaSeries` chart using `OxyPlot` in **Xamarin Forms**. It has three series.

1. Smooth = true, MarkerStroke = default, Result is as expected
2. Smooth = true, MarkerStroke = Yellow,  Thick lines appear over the line
3. Smooth = false, MarkerStroke = Yellow,  Result is as expected

So, when I use Smooth = true and define a color for MarkerStroke, it adds an unwanted thick line. How to fix / work around it?

**Note**: In Line Series, it works as expected. The problem is only on area series.

[image]

**Plot Model**

```
public class MyOxyPlotModelData
{
        public PlotModel AreaModel { get; set; }

        public MyOxyPlotModelData()
        {
             AreaModel = CreateAreaChart();

        }

        public PlotModel CreateAreaChart()
        {
            PlotModel plotModel1 = new PlotModel { Title = "Area" };
            var valueAxisX = new LinearAxis
            {
                Position = AxisPosition.Bottom,
                AxislineColor = OxyColors.White,
                TicklineColor = OxyColors.White,
                TextColor = OxyColors.White,
                FontSize = 12,
                IsZoomEnabled = false,
                IsPanEnabled = false
            };

            var valueAxisY = new LinearAxis
            {
                Position = AxisPosition.Left,
                //Maximum = 15,
                //Minimum = 0,
                AxislineColor = OxyColors.White,
                TicklineColor = OxyColors.White,
                TextColor = OxyColors.White,
                FontSize = 12,
                IsZoomEnabled = false,
                IsPanEnabled = false
            };

            plotModel1.Axes.Add(valueAxisX);
            plotModel1.Axes.Add(valueAxisY);

            plotModel1.DefaultColors = new List<OxyColor>
            {
                OxyColors.Purple,
                OxyColors.DeepPink,
                OxyColors.Teal 
                //OxyColor.FromRgb(0x20, 0x4A, 0x87)
            };

            AreaSeries areaSeries1 = new AreaSeries
            {
                MarkerType = MarkerType.Circle,
                MarkerSize = 2,
                //MarkerStroke = OxyColors.White,
                StrokeThickness = 1,
                Smooth = true
            };
            areaSeries1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(0, 50));
            areaSeries1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(10, 140));
            areaSeries1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(20, 80));


            AreaSeries areaSeries2 = new AreaSeries
            {
                MarkerType = MarkerType.Circle,
                MarkerSize = 2,
                MarkerStroke = OxyColors.Yellow,
                StrokeThickness = 1,
                Smooth = true
            };
            areaSeries2.Points.Add(new DataPoint(0, 30));
            areaSeries2.Points.Add(new DataPoint(15, 150));
            areaSeries2.Points.Add(new DataPoint(20, 20));


            AreaSeries areaSeries3 = new AreaSeries
            {
                MarkerType = MarkerType.Circle,
                MarkerSize = 2,
                MarkerStroke = OxyColors.Yellow,
                StrokeThickness = 1,
                Smooth = false
            };
            areaSeries3.Points.Add(new DataPoint(0, 40));
            areaSeries3.Points.Add(new DataPoint(15, 110));
            areaSeries3.Points.Add(new DataPoint(20, 55));

            plotModel1.Series.Add(areaSeries1);
            plotModel1.Series.Add(areaSeries2);
            plotModel1.Series.Add(areaSeries3);


            return plotModel1;

        }
}
```

**App. XAML.cs**

```
public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var vSampleData = new MyOxyPlotModelData();

        MainPage = new OxyPlotNewSeries.MainPage { BindingContext = vSampleData };

    }
```

**MainPage.XAML**

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:OxyPlotNewSeries"
             xmlns:oxy="clr-namespace:OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms;assembly=OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms" 
             x:Class="OxyPlotNewSeries.MainPage">

    <AbsoluteLayout>

        <oxy:PlotView Model="{Binding AreaModel}" BackgroundColor="#000000"
                  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="10,30,.9,.9"
                  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="WidthProportional,HeightProportional" />
    </AbsoluteLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Smoothing generates a lot of intermediate points. When you define a marker it draws a marker in all those points.The thick line is just markers close together. You get around it by not adding a marker.

Comment: Like @PalleDue pointed out, if you don't want it, don't use it. Though if the Thickness is your dislike I don't see `MarkerStrokeThickness` property set anywhere?

Comment: @PalleDue Why is it working fine in line series and not in area series? Please see the screenshot in the question

Comment: Do you mean why does area have the line at the bottom? Or what? Area would be drawing a Path shape with curves in points, the Line is just a line with curves in points so it has no border stroke like a shape does.

Comment: @ChrisW. In the line, there are six marker strokes only shown as white circles (since there are six entries in the original data set). But in the area chart,  I am not seeing the three data points that are present in the original data set. All I can see is a thick yellow curve. I want to see 3 yellow circles on the area series.

Comment: @Lijo: But you have smoothed the area graph. That has removed your old points and added a slew of new points. Those points are shown as markers. If you want, you can add another series with the old points, but they probably won't be on the smooth curve.

Comment: @PalleDue My question is why it is not happening to line series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option you have is to use `TwoColorAreaSeries` instead, as the problem you're describing does NOT happen for this series type.

[image]

```
TwoColorAreaSeries areaSeries2 = new TwoColorAreaSeries
{
    MarkerType = MarkerType.Circle,
    MarkerSize = 5,
    MarkerStroke = OxyColors.Yellow,
    MarkerStrokeThickness = 5,
    StrokeThickness = 1,
    Smooth = true
};
areaSeries2.Points.Add(new DataPoint(0, 30));
areaSeries2.Points.Add(new DataPoint(15, 140));
areaSeries2.Points.Add(new DataPoint(20, 20));
```

**EDIT:** Is it a bug? It could be... although judging by their own examples, it seems it was meant to be this way for drawing things like this:

[image]

and this:

[image]

Comment: So, is it a bug in AreaSeries?

Comment: Please see my **EDIT**.